# Html Javascript Audio Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement a html audio player in my project having playlist with it. I gone through many jquery plugins (jplayer,etc...) but that does not fulfill my requirement.

Actually a listing of songs will should be displayed to user having other information with it like (rating,price,time,buy now). Jplayer library provides a utility of playing plylist but there song list is not easily customizable.

Can anybody please help me with an example of such a audio player or near about this  or any instructions regarding the same would be great help.

Thanks

Comment: With a simple "HTML 5 audio player" google power :
[10 HTML5 Player](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-html5-audio-players)

Comment: Conversely, you can customize it. I am using jPlayer. It is good to make what you want.

Comment: @Habip But this is generating the html from jquery , If I want to add more fields in the play list then how it is possible ? it is generating whole html from the js file

Comment: I did not add rating section. But I think adding div, like <div id="rating"></div>, to loop than showing information about rating with jQuery must be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple demo for Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/yJfbX/2/

The playlist is a plain unordered list so it is easy customizable via CSS. Please consider this as a simple proof of concept to create your own playlist, since I've not considered different audio container than mp3

markup

```
<ul id="playlist">
    <li data-src="http://....mp3">title 1</li>
    <li data-src="http://....mp3">title 2</li>
    <li data-src="http://....mp3">title 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
var audio    = new Audio();
    playlist = $('#playlist');

    playlist.on('click', 'li', function() {
        playlist.find('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        audio.src = $(this).data('src');
        audio.play();
    });

audio.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this music player demo](http://www.codebasehero.com/files/music-player/demo/), looks like it might suit the build.

Comment: Again the field are limited in it....I need something like this http://www.jeejuh.com/